# copy&paste: diacritics and special characters

Tags: luatex, font-encodings, copy-paste

Why can't I correctly copy&paste from my pdf documents (created by LuaLaTeX)? E.g., I get `Faḫr al-Din̄ al-Rāzī` instead of `Faḫr al-Dīn al-Rāzī`. 
Surprisingly, most other things (including Arabic text, Greek text, umlauts work well).

I use (almost without any options):

- hyperref
- csquotes
- babel
- microtype
- xspace
- ellipsis

Comment: Which font do you use? Please: MWE.